# Problem numbering environment

Tags: numbering, tcolorbox

I want to use this code below to define theorems style:

```
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within = section]{mytheorem}{\emph{Teorema}}
{colback = blue!10,
colframe = blue!50!black,
fonttitle = \bfseries}{th}
```

I'm having problems to numbering it with the other environments, like definition for example. I tried to define a "ghost" counter

```
\newcounter{count} \numberwithin{count}{section}
\theoremstyle{definition}       
\newtheorem{definition}[count]{\protect\definitionname}
```

So just change ***number within = section*** for ***number within = count*** .

It almost work, but now theorems are numbered like "1.2.1",  "1.3.1" and so on while definitions (and others) are numbered like "1.2" "1.3" ...

How can I fix this?

***Edit: Here's the code used in my initial problem***

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}             %tcolorbox para caixas.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{count} \numberwithin{count}{section}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within = count]{teo}{\emph{Teorema}}
{colback = blue!10,
colframe = blue!50!black,
fonttitle = \bfseries}{th}

\theoremstyle{definition}           % use "definition-style" font for the rest.
\newtheorem{definition}[count]{\protect\definitionname}
\providecommand{\definitionname}{Def}

\title{Test document}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\maketitle
    \tableofcontents
\section{Test section 1}

Here is the section 
\begin{definition}
Test definition. 1
\end{definition}

\begin{teo}{Teo 1}{}
Test theorem. 1
\end{teo}

\section{Test section 2}

Here is the section  2
\begin{definition}
Test definition. 2
\end{definition}

\begin{teo}{Teo 2}{}
Test theorem. 2
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use option `use counter=<counter>` instead of `number within`.

Comment: In fact, this corrects the problem with the theorem environment, but it screwed up with everyone else.

Comment: Can you provide a _complete example_ to demonstrate the new problem?

Comment: For sure, now there's a concrete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}            
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% new theorem "definition", this defines new counter "definition"
\theoremstyle{definition}           
\newtheorem{definition}{Def}[section]

% new theorem "teo", numbered like "definition"
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=definition]
  {teo}{\emph{Teorema}}{
    colback = blue!10,
    colframe = blue!50!black,
    fonttitle = \bfseries
  }{th}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}

\begin{definition} 
Test definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{teo}{Teo}{}
Test theorem.
\end{teo}

\begin{definition}
Test definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
Test definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{teo}{Teo}{}
Test theorem.
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You just save my day, thanks!

Comment: @Syr Answer is updated to make use of option `use counter*`. It gives simpler input.