# Use theorem counters in custom tcolorboxes

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems, counters

I want my custom boxes to use the same counter as my theorems. I took a look in the tcbox manual and tried various things like "use counter from=theorem" and so on but probably it doesn't work like this:

[image]

This is a mwe of the above picture. :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

%Theorems

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

% Boxes

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{abox}[2][]{%
    colback=green!5!white,colframe=green!50!black,
    enhanced,
    colbacktitle=green!50!black, 
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-2mm},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=\faPencil\ Exercise~\thetcbcounter: #2,#1}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{bbox}[2][]{%
    colback=blue!5!white,
    enhanced,
    colframe=blue!50!black,
    colbacktitle=blue!50!black, 
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-2mm},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=\faPaperclip\ Example~\thetcbcounter #2,#1}



\begin{document}

\section{Section 1} 
    \begin{theorem} Hello, I am a theorem.
    \end{theorem}   
This is some random text.
    \begin{definition} Let $A$ blabla
    \end{definition}    
    
    \begin{abox}{Differential Equations} This exercise should have the counter 1.3 \end{abox}
    
\section{Section 2} 
    \begin{definition} asdf \end{definition}
    \begin{bbox}{} This example should have the counter 2.2 \end{bbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `\tcolorboxenvironment{bbox}`?

Comment: Use option `use counter*=<counter name>`. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548003/79060

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Perfect! Thanks. Should I close this question since it already exists?